# Why does the read() in FileInputStream return an integer?

Tags: java, byte, fileinputstream

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) page shows says that it is so that the method can return -1 when it wants to indicate that there are no more bytes to be read.

But a byte ranges from -128 to 127, right? And wouldn't it make more sense for the return type of read() to be byte since it returns a byte?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for it returning the value as an `int` is that it needs to return a value between 0-255, as well as being able to indicate when there is no more bytes to read from the file. By using an `int`, you can return the full range of positive unsigned values 0-255, as well as indicate when the file is complete. It wouldn't be able to provide this with only the 256 distinct values of a `byte` value, half of which are negative by Java default.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) go on to say..

> **Returns:**
>       ***the total number of bytes read*** into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the file has been reached.

Hopefully more than 127 bytes can be read from a stream at a time.

Comment: I made this mistake at first too - the read() method actually returns a single byte of data, not the number of bytes that can be read. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I think you read the wrong method's documentation. You read the one for **public int read(byte[] b)** where as I'm referring to **public int read()**

Comment: There are several different `read()` methods.  One returns a single byte; others fill an array and return the _number_ of bytes that were read.

Comment: I was referring to the method that doesn't need any arguments. Since that's the method that's also used in the example given in the link that I pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

A byte of data is an unsigned value with a range from `0` to `255`, while a `byte` in java is defined to range from `-128` to `127`, which doesn't make sense when reading binary data.  `read()` returns an integer to allow it to use all of the non-negative values to represent valid data, and a negative value to signal end of data.

In general, a function should indicate an error condition or exception using a *different* mechanism from the one it uses to return data.  In the simplest case, it can return a value that cannot be used to represent valid data, to ensure its meaning is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: wouldn't it make more sense for the return type of read() to be
>   byte?

A: No, because "byte" can't return the whole range 0..255 (unsigned), and "short" is just a PITA.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking maybe by using internal bit-level manipulations the data could be stored in the signed format itself. That was dumb but, I see now. Anyway, I'm curious to know why short is a PITA?

Comment: PITA == "Pain In The gluteus mAximus" ;)

Comment: Just because numbers in Java default to being `int` values, so if it were a `short` you would need to do conversions from `short` to `int`, even if the conversions are handled automatically by the Java engine

Answer (score 0):

The FileInputStream class makes it possible to read the contents of a file as a stream of bytes. Here is a simple example:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input-text.txt");

int data = input.read();
while(data != -1) {
  //do something with data...
  doSomethingWithData(data);

  data = input.read();
}
input.close();
```

Note: The proper exception handling has been skipped here for the sake of clarity. To learn more about correct exception handling, go to Java IO Exception Handling.

The read() method of a FileInputStream returns an int which contains the byte value of the byte read. If the read() method returns -1, there is no more data to read in the stream, and it can be closed. That is, -1 as int value, not -1 as byte value. There is a difference here!

Comment: -1 because of "That is, -1 as int value, not -1 as byte value. There is a difference here!". What is evaluation of `( (byte) -1 ) == ( (int) -1 )`? It is `true` of course because byte is from -128 to 127 which means -1 is also legal byte value.